# Noncommutative rings and prime/maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ a non-simple noncommutative ring, and let $\mathcal{I}$ the set of non-trivial (right, left) ideals of $R$, with the following property: "Every element $I \in \mathcal{I}$ is prime and/or maximal".
There exists an example of such $R$?

Comment: What does "(right, left) ideals of $R$" mean? You want us to choose either one? or you mean both, so that they are two-sided ideals? You should just say two-sided ideals, if you want to emphasize that.

Comment: When you say "noncommutative" do you mean "not necessarily commutative" like everyone else?  Or you want it to be not commutative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb H\times \mathbb H$ where $\mathbb H$ denotes Hamilton's quaternions.

It has four right ideals, all of which are two sided, two of which are trivial, and the other two are maximal and prime.

Comment: Thanks! The same occurs with $\mahtbb{H}^{n} = \underbrace{\mathbb{H} \times \ldots \times \mathbb{H}_{n \ \mbox{times}}$?

Comment: @674123173797-4 Yes, it does.